# Mock class members before the ngAfterContentInit hook is called

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have a component that queries its content child like below

```
@ContentChild(InputControlDirective, { read: ElementRef })
public inputControl: ElementRef;
```

I have the ngAfterContentInit hook that checks if the `inputControl` has a value, otherwise I throw a custom error

```
public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        if (!this.inputControl) {
                throw new Error(
                    'Provide a InputControlDirective for the field used with the form-input component like  <input inputControl>'
                );
            }
}
```

How can I mock the `inputControl` before the ngAfterContentInit hook for the unit test below?

```
describe('FormInputComponent', () => {
    let component: FormInputComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormInputComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormInputComponent],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormInputComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
    });
```

Is the component implementation the one making the unit testing a challenge?

Answer (score 0):

After some reading, I was able to figure out why my attempt of mocking the class members did not work.

**Before**

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormInputComponent],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormInputComponent);

        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        component.control = {} as FormControlName;
        component.inputControl = {} as ElementRef;


        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

**After**

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormInputComponent],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormInputComponent);

        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        component.control = {} as FormControlName;
        component.inputControl = {} as ElementRef;


        setTimeout(() => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
    });
```

Note the `setTimeout`.

From the Angular [documentation](https://Delayed%20change%20detection%20is%20intentional%20and%20useful.%20It%20gives%20the%20tester%20an%20opportunity%20to%20inspect%20and%20change%20the%20state%20of%20the%20component%20before%20Angular%20initiates%20data%20binding%20and%20calls%20lifecycle%20hooks.)

> Delayed change detection is intentional and useful. It gives the
> tester an opportunity to inspect and change the state of the component
> before Angular initiates data binding and calls lifecycle hooks.

Comment: So you do ngAfterContentInit before ngInit() and all other hooks, and thats somehow ok with you ?? :) I guess we can ommit lifecycle if nothing is happening there.

Comment: I have updated the answer, I forgot to remove  this `component.ngAfterContentInit();`. Thanks for bringing that to my attention :)